# Making jokes and being funny by nature

Tags: halal-haram

Salam, and I want to say that it is a really serious question,

I want to know if it is prohibited to make "jokes" not necessary on people, but to be funny by nature,

I always need to turn normal, serious, sad, situation into funny moments by bringing some humour, I use exagerations alot, and it is quiet a habit in my familly. Not all people like it but I've always been like that.

Should I avoid it ? I know that Lokman spoke about this topic to his son but I want more verses/Hadiths

**EDITION :**
I do not "laugh" high (I rarelly laugh), it's in general in low voice, I notice some things that people around me do not see and it's in general funny, It's not "clown" behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jokes are not prohibited but we should limit how much we joke around.

Per hadith, those who remember death often are the [wisest](https://sunnah.com/urn/1343990) so if you're turning serious situations whereby people are remembering Allah (ﷻ) into "funny moments" where their attention is diverted, it's a foolish thing to do. Moreover, if your goal is to make people laugh then it's said that excessive laughing [deadens the heart](https://sunnah.com/urn/1292950) which is because, same reason, it leads to distraction and heedlessness of what's important.

Does that mean Islam has no place for humor? No. It just means that there is a time and place for this along with boundaries. Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) himself sometimes also used humor to teach people, but it was always good and informative.. and it wasn't a constant thing.

وعليكم السلام ورحمة الله وبركاته